# i cant install ubuntu using pendrive usb installer

Tags: installation, usb, usb-drive

i have tried countless times to install ubuntu to my laptop/ netbook, but to no avail, i have followed all the instructions on this page:http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

(i need to use a usb because my disk drive is broken) every time i try, i get a message saying that windows is unable to open the file, and it had me download DynSite, and when i tried to find the file it said it didnt exist. so if someone could please help me that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to make clear what you did, example: "when i tried to find the file it said it didnt exist" ?

Answer (score 1):

If the menssage you get appears when you install ubuntu on your laptop you have to select on boot the usb.

When you turn on your laptop, a key (F2, F4...) to boot options appears on monitor...or something like this. reboot you machine and press this key at the time it is appear, on boot options select USB.